# Re-opening ImagePlus file (imageJ)

Tags: java, imagej

I'd like to re-open an ImagePlus file I already called using show().

That is, I already called

```
imp.show()
```

I closed the window containing the image, but now I'd like to re-open the ImagePlus file in another window (via code). Unfortunately, calling imp.show() again doesn't work. Any ideas on how I can re-open it in a new ImageJ window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search in the [ImageJ mailing list](https://list.nih.gov/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=IMAGEJ;77d3c83c.1005) gives you the answer (by Michael Schmid):

> Closing an `ImageWindow` (`ImageWindow.close`) calls `imp.flush()`, which
>   deletes many class variables of the imp (essentially everything that
>   needs significant amounts of memory is set to null).

and suggests a possible solution:

> If you don't have a stack, a solution would be keeping a reference to
>   the ImageProcessor in the imp and keep it instead of imp (also the
>   roi). If you have no stack, you could also try to clone the ImagePlus
>   to get a copy that can be displayed again - memory consumption for
>   cloning would be rather low ('shallow cloning').